# What happens when a parameter is passed with the -- operator?

Tags: java, variables, operators

i came across following code in Java:

```
public static void foo (int a, int b) {
    System.out.println("a: " + a);
    System.out.println("b: " + b);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int c = 1;
    foo(c--, c);
    System.out.println("c: " + c);
//The output is:
//a: 1
//b: 0
//c: 0
```

Could someone please explain, why that is? I would have guessed it the other way round that only the first print-statement would be affected by `c--`. But if it did permanently change c's value why is the first print line still printed 1?

Comment: `c--` is a post-decrement operator. That means, it decrements the variable _after_ it returns a value from the expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increment by using `++c` or `c++`, similarly, you can decrement by using `--c` or `c--`

for `++c` and `--c`, you're effectively telling Java "Change the value, then do something with the new value"

for `c++` and `c--`, you're telling java "Load the value, then change it".

Now, that explains why A is 1, and C is 0.  But why is B also 0?

When you call a function, the arguments are resolved in order.  Usually this is only relevant if you're passing the direct results of a method as an argument.

for example, calling
`methodX( methodY(), methodZ())`
where the method signatures are
`void methodX(int a, int b);` `int methodY();` and `int methodZ();`, then method Y will execute before Z, which executes before X.